# How can i calculate statistics for a given type within an elasticsearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I know that the `_stats` API provides index level statistics for one or more indices. I'm particularly interested in the `store` parameter, which is the size of the index in bytes. I'd like to calculate the size in bytes for a given type within an index, however

`curl http://localhost:9200/myIndex/_stats/indexing?types=myType`

does not return the size in bytes for `myType`. Is there an API that would give me the statistics that would state: `myType` is Xgb in size and represents Y% of `myIndex` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `/store` sub-path instead of the `/indexing` sub-path like this:

```
curl http://localhost:9200/myIndex/_stats/store?types=myType
                                            ^
                                            |
                                     use "store" here
```

And you'll get all the `store` data you're interested in

```
{
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 15,
    "successful" : 15,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "_all" : {
    "primaries" : {
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 2250058413,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      }
    },
    "total" : {
      "store" : {
        "size_in_bytes" : 2250058413,
        "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
      }
    }
  },
  "indices" : {
    "myIndex" : {
      "primaries" : {
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 1444291,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        }
      },
      "total" : {
        "store" : {
          "size_in_bytes" : 1444291,
          "throttle_time_in_millis" : 0
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above only works with indexing.  You are specifying types, but you are still seeing the store for total of all types.